# Simultaneous transcendental equations involving digamma functions.

Tags: systems-of-equations, special-functions, transcendental-equations, digamma-function

Is there a way (can I hope) to express the solutions of the following coupled transcendental equations in a closed form (in terms of Lambert, hypergeometric or other special functions) :
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{1}=\operatorname{Im}[\Psi[A_{2}+i B_{2}-i C_{2} \phi_{2}]]\\
\phi_{2}=\operatorname{Im}[\Psi[A_{1}+i B_{1}-i C_{1} \phi_{1}]]
\end{eqnarray}
All constants ($A$'s, $B$'s and $C$'s) are real and positive. And $\operatorname{Im}[\Psi[z]]$ stands for imaginary part of digamma function of $z$.
As is clear from the equations I am looking for real solutions $(\phi_{1},\phi_{2})$ only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the special case of $B_{1}^{}=B_{2}^{}=0$, atleast one solution of the above equations can be identified as : $\phi_{1}^{}=\phi_{2}^{}=0$ (Follows from the property of digamma function : $\Psi[z] \in \mathbb{R}$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$).